# Custom Simple Scrollbar linked to Listview

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

The default scrollbar for a listview appears at the right.  I designed a new style and would like it to appear separate from the listview control.  What you see in the image is how I have it set up now using blend.

So how do I link the custom scroll bar to the listview?  I'm using Blend 4.

Listview Image located here:

http://i141.photobucket.com/albums/r69/thebirdbath/scroll.jpg

Comment: Do you want to apply this style to the `ScrollViewer` inside the `Template` and display it on the left side or do you want to define it outside of the `ListView`?

Comment: I think you could also "link them" by adding an attached behavior where you subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the `ListView` and in the event handler you find the `ScrollViewer` in the template and then sync them in both of their `ScrollChanged` events. I think you would also need to bind the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to add your Style to the `ScrollViewer` inside the `Template` of the `ListView` or if you want to disable that `ScrollViewer` and place the `ListView` in a separate `ScrollViewer`.

To apply the `Style` to the `ScrollViewer` in the `Template` and place the `ScrollBar` to the left you can modify the default `Template` when using `GridView`. It will require a reference to **PresentationFramework.Aero**

- Set `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` on the `ScrollViewer` to place it on the left side
- Set `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"` on the `ItemsPresenter` and `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` since they will inherit `RightToLeft` otherwise
- To get the transparent space between the `ScrollViewer` and the content, set `Background="Transparent"` for the `ListView` and set the desired `Background` on the `ItemsPanel` instead
- Control the transparent space with `Padding`, e.g. `Padding="0,0,10,0"`

Looks like this

[image]

```
<ListView xmlns:MS_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
          Padding="0,0,10,0"
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="0"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Background="White"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <MS_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              Style="{YourStyle...}"
                              FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewHeaderRowPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </MS_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, pretty close.  Its working but I've lost my column headers.  Also I can't get the transparency in between the bar and the listview.  Its like the bar is still attached and I want them to appear like they are separate.  (See the link to my original image)

This has been very helpful.  Almost there!

My code is below.
[image]

```
<ListView
                            AlternationCount="2"
                            Padding="0,0,10,0"
                            Shared:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"
                            Shared:GridViewSort.ShowSortGlyph="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Contents}" 
                            SelectionMode="Extended" 
                            Background="Transparent" 
                            Foreground="White" 
                            SelectionChanged="ListBoxSelectionChanged"
                            BorderThickness="0"

                            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Background="Transparent"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <MS_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              Style="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerKey}"
                              FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewHeaderRowPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </MS_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
```